# how can i see that $j\beta =\beta j$ is equivalent to $\beta^*+\beta$ being a multiple of the identity?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, differential, contact-topology

A vector field $X$ is said to be conformal if $L_Xj=0$  where j is the almost complex structure. The conformality condition is equivalent to $j\beta =\beta j$. Where $\beta : ker(\theta) \mapsto ker(\theta)$ such that $\beta(u)= \nabla_uX$ and $\theta$ is contact form such that $\theta(X)=1$. \
my question is how can i see that $j\beta =\beta j$ is equivalent to $\beta^*+\beta$ being a multiple of the identity? \
What are the conditions so that i can see $ j=\beta-\beta^*$?

Comment: $\theta$ is the contact form defined as $\theta=g(X,-)$. Where $g$ is the Riemanian metric on the manifold M and X is the Reeb vector field. $\beta^*$ is the adjoint of the map $\beta : ker(\theta) \mapsto ker(\theta)$ defined as $ \beta(u)= \nabla_uX$ and $g(\beta(Y),Z)=g(\beta^*(Z),Y)$.